# How to choose the correct radius to prove set is open?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a general question, which is when proving that a ball is open, I know that I need to show that for an arbitrary point in the set $x_0$ there exists a ball $ B $ such that $B (x_0, r)$ is completely contained in the original set $S$ but I have a hard time choosing a radius $r$ that works. All the examples that I have seen seem so arbitrary. Can someone explain to me whats the criteria for choosing a correct radius? Here is an example to illustrate:

Let $B= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: |x| < 1 ,  |y| <1 \}  $

Why do we then choose $r =min \{1- |a|, 1- |b| \}$

or are there any other more intutive choices and why?

Thanks a whole lot!

Comment: It is a geometric decision, we have to avoid the boundary. Make a sketch. Trouble comes if $x$ is close to $1$ or $-1$, or $y$ is close to $1$ or $-1$, then we have to make $r$ small. I would be tempted to choose $r= (1/2)\sqrt{(1-|a|)^2+(1-|b|)^2}$, the $1/2$ for overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose any radius you like, as long as it is small enough. If you pick any radius, [what could possibly go wrong?](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhatCouldPossiblyGoWrong) Well, you could have points in your $B(x_0,r)$ that are outside $S$. Therefore you should make sure that no points at distance less than $r$  are outside. In the given example, you should specifically avoid points with $x\ge1$, so you better pick $r$ such that $a+r\le 1$. Similarly, you want to avoid points with $x\le -1$, so you better ensure that $a-r\ge -1$. These two conditions can be summarized to $r\le1-|a|$. Similarly, from the other coordinate we find that we should have $r\le1-|b|$. To obey both, we shuld pick $r\le \min\{1-|a|,1-|b|\}$. Of course the simplest choice for $r$ with this restriction is just $r=\min\{1-|a|,1-|b|\}$. Fortunately, this $r$ is $>0$, for both $|a|<1$ and $|b|<1$ follow from $(a,b)\in S$.

Comment: Light. Bulb. 
THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Draw $B$ (It's a solid square in the plane). Now draw a point near one of the corners, say at $(1.8,0.4)$. Now, what is the largest ball you can draw around that point such that the ball is still contained inside the square? Well the shortest distance from the point to the boundary of the square is $0.2$, so a ball of radius $0.2$ will be fully contained in the square.

If we think about this more abstractly, and consider *any* point $(x,y)$ in the square, then the shortest distance from the point to an edge of the square will always be either the horizontal or vertical distance (which is why we take the minimum of these two) and then $1-|x|$ is obviously the horizontal distance, and $1-|y|$ is the vertical distance.